# Ways to show stability in array of numbers between 0-1

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

I have some results from algorithms that return mean squared error values between 0-1. One of these algorithms shows much more stable results, and I want to show that with e.g., standard deviation or variance. However, due to the numbers being 0.23, 0.25, 0.31, both metrics don't work that well due to the variance and standard deviations being very very low, which does not show the very clear better stability of that one algorithm (e.g., algorithm1 has now a standard deviation of 0.006 and the better one 0.003. This does not rely convey that well how much better one algorithm works over the other. What is a better way to show this result with such numbers?

Comment: If one algorithm yields half the standard deviation of the others, that seems clear enough. What is the problem?

Comment: Yeah i know but i was just wondering if there are other metrics that i can use to make the numbers a bit higher to make the message a bit more clearer. Now a reader could think easily think that one algorithm having half the standard deviation does not really matter if it only differs 0.003 thats what I am hinting at.